# Datamapper Query Returns Hex in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper

After successfully creating records using Datamapper and a MySql database, I now want to query the database using Ruby. My code as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'simple_statistics'
require 'dm-aggregates'
require 'descriptive-statistics'

#Connect to mysql database
DataMapper.setup(:default, {
:adapter  => 'mysql',
:host     => 'localhost',
:database => 'Kourarau',
:username => '***********',
:password => '***********'
})

class StnA
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,       Serial, :key => true
    property :datetime, DateTime
    property :stn_time, Integer
    property :stna_kW,  Integer
    property :total_kW,     Integer
    property :stna_kVAr,    Integer
    property :total_kVAr,   Integer
    property :tailrace, Integer
    property :lo_pond,  Integer
    property :up_pond,  Integer
    property :mode,     String
    property :pen_a_press,  Integer
    property :pen_b_press,  Integer
    property :volt_A,   Integer
    property :stat_A,   String
    property :surge,    Decimal, precision: 4, scale: 1
    property :needle_a1,    Integer
    property :needle_b1,    Integer
    property :needle_a2,    Integer
    property :needle_b2,    Integer
end

DataMapper.finalize

puts StnA.last(:up_pond)
```

This returns the following (example)

StnA:0xa396b10

I want to return the last record of the field up_pond in the Table StnA. The actual value in the database is an integer (-135 in the above example)

How do I convert what Datamapper is returning to an integer thats useful?

Comment: does this do the job StnA.last.up_pond

Comment: Sure does. Thanks Zahid. I couldn't seem to find that in the Datamapper documentation.